# Definite Integral Using Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute the following using contour integration:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^8+1}dx$$
I've seen integrals of $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)}$ using contour integration by making using $\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}$.
Do I use a similar method for this problem?

Comment: Yes, along with the fact that the integrand is even to extend integral on entire real axis.  With this integrand, there are just more poles to count.

Comment: Alternately, since the integrand is symmetric under the rotation $z \mapsto \exp \frac{\pi i}{4} z$, one can use a contour along the boundary of a sector of radius $R$ with vertex at the origin and sides along the positive $x$-axis and the ray from the origin through $\exp \frac{\pi i}{4}$. This contour has the modest advantage that it only contains a single pole.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^8+1}$ is a fast-decaying function as $|z|\to+\infty$, the integral of $f(z)$ on a half-circle with radius $R$ centered in the origin, belonging to the region $\text{Im}(z)\geq 0$, goes to zero as $R\to +\infty$. That just gives:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^8+1}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dz}{z^8+1}=\pi i\sum_{\xi\in Z}\text{Res}(f(z),z=\xi) $$
where $Z$ is the set of the poles of $f(z)$ in the upper half-plane, namely:
$$ Z=\left\{\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{8}\right),\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}{8}\right),\exp\left(\frac{5\pi i}{8}\right),\exp\left(\frac{7\pi i}{8}\right)\right\}.$$
You can also replace $x^8+1$ by $u$, then exploit the properties of the Beta function and the reflection formula for the $\Gamma$ function to prove that:
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{8\sin\frac{\pi}{8}}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}.$$